# how to print login_days with user_stats module?

Tags: 6, users, nodes

```
<?php print format_date(user_stats_get_stats('login_days', $node->uid), 'custom', 'j'); ?>
```

Returns "1" always, how to use user_stats - login_days correctly?

Comment: Does the the output of `user_stats_get_stats('login_days', 1)` displays correct information ?

Comment: More important, *what* does that display? format_date() is used to display a *unix timestamp* as a date. It is very possible that user_stats_get_stats() does *not* return a date, but simply a number or so. And if it returns for example "80", using that as a unix timestamp means 01.01.1970 01:20, using "j" (the day of the month) returns 1.

Comment: @Berdir That should be an answer.

Comment: @kiamluno: It's kinda an answer yes. But I'm just guessing here, I'll convert it into an answer once @Heihachi responds what the actual output of that function is.

Comment: @tostinni, tried user_stats_get_stats('login_days', 1) and its returns nothing.
@Berdir, as it mentioned in readme: login_days — number of days since the user was last logged-in to the site; found it here http://www.apaddedcell.com/an-introduction-user-stats-module-drupal, but there's no examples on how to use login_days function :(

Comment: @Berdir Comments are just for asking what is not clear in the question; if you make a statement about a function, then that should be an answer. Answers are sometimes guesses basing on what reported in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Berdir stated in the comment, `user_stats_get_stats('login_days'...)` returns a number of days so you can't use this with `format_date`, also I tried this on my site and if you're the author of the node this function will return nothing, but if you try with other users that have logged in, this should display the number of days since their last access.

In fact if you're only using this module for this function, it may be a little overkill and you should better do this manually:

```
$u = user_load(31);
print floor((time() - $u->access) / 86400);
```

Edit: 12/06 11:57
If you want to format the last access date then do:

```
$u = user_load(31);
print format_date($u->access, 'custom', 'j M H:i');
//will display 12 Jun 12:03 with hour formated in 24H.
```

Comment: Thanks, but it displays 151351 as last login date for all profiles :( What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Heihachi it's because the user never logged in the site so access is empty. Test it first.

Comment: @Tostinni: hmm.. i've checked the most active users and on all user profiles the same 151351.

Tested again for sure, but its same, no difference. 
Checked this page http://ruh.kz/admin/user/user/list, and it says that user i was testing on, was last seen 10 hours ago, but in profile it says 151351

Comment: @Heihachi you're using the uid right ? When you make a `$u = user_load($uid); dpm($u);` does the access is defined ? Seems very strange :(

Comment: it works, sorry :) another question - it displays only days ago the user last seen, can i use format_date to this somehow?

Comment: @Heihachi what do you qant to format/display?

Comment: @Tostinni: i want to format last login date. With your code above it displays: User's last login on the site was 2 days ago. 

I want to display it this way: User's last login on the site was 12 June at 13:25

Comment: @Heihachi I updated my answer.

Comment: @Heihachi tough sell :D but glad it helps you ;)